# Acumatica Vendor ID segment key different to BIZZACCOUNT segment length

Tags: acumatica

I want to know if it's possible to setup Vendor ID segment keys with a less number of characters than the BiZAccounts..
For example I have created branch Keys like USBRANCH1 but now I want to create Vendor ID like V001 but not give the user possibility to enter more than 4 characters?
I'm not sure why BIZaccount is tied to vendors, customers, employees in terms of segment keys as this reduces flexibility and changing key length and type

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve that:
1. Create your own Segmented Key like below:

[image]

2. Create Cache Extension to the Vendor's DAC to change Default `VENDOR` Segmented Key which is inherited from `BIZACCT`to yours `MYVENDOR` like below:

   ```
   using PX.Data;
   using PX.Data.EP;
   using PX.Objects.AP;
   using PX.Objects.CR;
   using PX.Objects.GL;
   using System;
   namespace ClassLibrary1.DAC
   {
       public class VendorExt:PXCacheExtension<Vendor>
       {
           [MyVendorRaw(IsKey = true)]
           [PXDefault]
           [PXFieldDescription]
           public virtual string AcctCD { get; set; }
       }

       [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
       public sealed class MyVendorRawAttribute : AcctSubAttribute
       {
           public MyVendorRawAttribute() : this(null)
           {
           }

           public MyVendorRawAttribute(Type where)
           {
               Type type = BqlCommand.Compose(new Type[]
               {
                   typeof(Search2<, , >),
                   typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
                   typeof(LeftJoin<Contact, On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<Vendor.bAccountID>, And<Contact.contactID, Equal<Vendor.defContactID>>>, LeftJoin<Address, On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<Vendor.bAccountID>, And<Address.addressID, Equal<Vendor.defAddressID>>>>>),
                   (where == null) ? typeof(Where<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>) : BqlCommand.Compose(new Type[]
                   {
                       typeof(Where2<, >),
                       typeof(Where<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>),
                       typeof(And<>),
                       where
                   })
               });
               PXDimensionSelectorAttribute pxdimensionSelectorAttribute;
               this._Attributes.Add(pxdimensionSelectorAttribute = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute("MYVENDOR", type, typeof(Vendor.acctCD), new Type[]
               {
                   typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
                   typeof(Vendor.acctName),
                   typeof(Vendor.vendorClassID),
                   typeof(Vendor.status),
                   typeof(Contact.phone1),
                   typeof(Address.city),
                   typeof(Address.countryID)
               }));
               pxdimensionSelectorAttribute.DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName);
               this._SelAttrIndex = this._Attributes.Count - 1;
               this.Filterable = true;
               ((PXDimensionSelectorAttribute)this._Attributes[this._SelAttrIndex]).CacheGlobal = true;
           }

           public const string DimensionName = "MYVENDOR";
       }
   }
   ```

After this `Vendor CD` will work with **4** length. But as you can see on the screenshot below there will be some issues with the existing records. So I recommend you to do this only in case if the system has not existing Vendors.
Also after doing this I assume you to check all the pages which use Vendor for correct working.

[image]